# how can make a image slideShow in ios using swift its only show one image?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myScrView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pagectr: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myScrView.tag = 1
        myScrView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.None
        self.view.addSubview(myScrView)
        self.setupScrollView(myScrView)

        pagectr.tag = 12
        pagectr.numberOfPages = 9
        pagectr.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.None
        self.view.addSubview(pagectr)
    }

    func setupScrollView(scrMain:UIScrollView) -> Void {
        var imgesArray : NSMutableArray = []
        for position in 1...9 {
            var strImage : String = "\(position).jpeg"
            var imges = UIImage(named: strImage)
            imgesArray.addObject(imges!)

            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
            imageView.image = imges
            imageView.tag = position+1
            scrMain.addSubview(imageView)
            println(imageView)
        }

        scrMain.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrMain.frame.size.width*10, scrMain.frame.size.height)
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "scrollingTimer", userInfo:nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func scrollingTimer(){

        let scrMain: UIScrollView = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as UIScrollView
        let pgctr: UIPageControl = self.view.viewWithTag(12) as UIPageControl
        let contentOffset  = scrMain.contentOffset.x as CGFloat
        var nextPage = (CGFloat)(contentOffset/scrMain.frame.size.width) + 1
        if(nextPage != 9){
            scrMain.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(nextPage*scrMain.frame.size.width, 0, scrMain.frame.size.width, scrMain.frame.size.height), animated: true)
            pgctr.currentPage = Int(nextPage)
        }
        else{
            scrMain.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(0, 0, scrMain.frame.size.width, scrMain.frame.size.height), animated: true)
            pgctr.currentPage = 1
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make a image slide show app using swift in ios please help me it's show only one image.I get a blank screen, almost as if the animations aren't keeping up, and then when I wait a moment and swipe again the image views speed up into place and works normally again. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? What is the best practice when it comes to implementing an image carousel like this with a dynamic amount of images (here they're hardcoded)?